# how to input individual values in a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I come from an excel VBA program ming background where it is very easy to input data into

(1) every cell in a column, 
(2) every cell in a row, or 
(3) a single cell e.g. B1 This can be done as an array or directly into a worksheet.

Does a pandas dataframe, which is effectively a grid, have the ability to add an item into a specific row and column intersection?

I know it is very good at processing data for an entire row or column with millions of rows very quickly, but can it (a pandas dataframe) have single data items put inside it.

Think of the following diagram (columns A and B as an existing dataframe, and then I want to add the data item X to a new second column in the second row.

```
   A | B | C | D | 
 1| a|   |   |   |
 ------------------
 2| b| x |   |   |
 ------------------
 3| c|   |   |   |
 ------------------
 5| d|   |   |   |
 ------------------
 6| e|   |   |   |
```

**Can this be done?**

Comment: Yes, use `loc`, `iloc`, or `ix`. Assumming your row index really does start at one (typically starts with zero in pandas) you can, for example, do (for a dataframe called df): `df.loc[2,'B'] = 'x'`. The [10 minutes to pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) covers this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde')}, columns=list('ABCDE'))
> df
   A    B    C    D    E
0  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
> df.B[2] = 'x'
> df.loc[3, 'C'] = 'y'
> df
   A    B    C    D    E
0  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  c    x  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  d  NaN    y  NaN  NaN
4  e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Don't use chained indexing, prefer using `.loc`, `.iloc` and `.ix` instead see the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) so for this example you should use `df.loc[2,'B'] = 'x'`